# What is the difference between these two registry settings involved in downloading more than 2 files at a time for IE8+

Tags: download, windows-registry, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to determine what each of these affect.  Adding a `DWORD` to both of these settings for `iexplore.exe` and setting the `decimal` value to `10` allows your to create more connections to servers when using IE, but Im curious why there are 2 entries...

What is the difference between:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_MAXCONNECTIONSPER1_0SERVER

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_MAXCONNECTIONSPERSERVER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one sets the connection limit that you want for HTTP 1.0 connections, and the second one is for HTTP 1.1 connections.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol):

> HTTP/1.1 is a revision of the original HTTP (HTTP/1.0). In HTTP/1.0 a separate connection to the same server is made for every resource request. HTTP/1.1 can reuse a connection multiple times to download images, scripts, stylesheets et cetera after the page has been delivered. HTTP/1.1 communications therefore experience less latency as the establishment of TCP connections presents considerable overhead.